# RubyMine 2019.1 can't run rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rubymine, rbenv

I got a Rails project that uses Ruby 2.5.3 and I can run `bin/rake --tasks` from the terminal just fine:

```
$ rbenv version 
# 2.5.3 (set by /Users/me/myproject/.ruby-version)
```

However, I get a message each time RubyMine telling me that `rake --tasks` can't be executed.
This is more of a nuisance than a real problem but I still want to get this fixed.

Interestingly, a different rubyframework `2.6.0` is used and it is the "native" ruby rather than one of my `rbenv` installations:

```
Error:[rake --tasks] /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.2) required by your /Users/besi/Dropbox/projects/boexli/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.2`
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Error:[rake --prereqs] /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.2) required by your /Users/besi/Dropbox/projects/boexli/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.2`
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

I think, if I could change that framework `2.6` to my default `2.5.3` the issue would be resolved, but I can't seem to find that setting.

[image: Messages]

The SDK from which that task is executed  does not show up the SDK Dialog at all.

[image: sdks]

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot of your SDK settings (Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Ruby SDK and Gems)? Which SDK is used for that project?

Comment: @Olivia I did but the mysterious sdk does not show up there...

Comment: According to the screenshot the project SDK isn't a rbenv one, could you please re-configure it and set SDK named 'rbenv: 2.5.3'?